# PHP odbc_fetch_row. Showing only certain row

Tags: php, odbc

I have a procedure that outputs a table with 4 columns and 2 rows. I want data on the 3rd column and second row. The code here gives me the row data for the different columns as i change them below but it outputs the first and second row data for the 3rd column like this: row1datarow2data. Its both row values and I only want the 2nd row. Can someone please help me fix this.

Thanks.

```
<?php
$result=odbc_exec($conn, $query); 

//fetch tha data from the database 
while(odbc_fetch_row($result))
{

echo "<tr>"; 

echo "<td>";

//if i change the 3 under here to a 2 I get the other two row values for the 2nd,column.
echo odbc_result($result,3);
 ?>
```

Comment: You do realize that you have a missing closing brace `}` - typo?

Comment: yeah i just forgot to copy it, the code runs fine.

Comment: I kinda figured. I like to dot the `i`'s and bar the `T`'s ;)

Comment: Do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: @user3890598 - if you only want the second row, I'd suggest changing the query so it only returns the row you want to process. If that's not possible, I'd suggest adding an `if` statement inside your loop to track how many rows you've retrieved, so you can fetch the data when you've retrieved the second one. Alternatively - call `odbc_fetch_row()` twice; the first time, you can just ignore it, but it means when you call it a second time, you'll be fetching the row you want

Comment: Changing the query is not possible. Could you please give me an example of the other two solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have shown it is going to loop through all the records and echo the column value specified in your call to *odbc_result()*.

If you do not want to echo the value from the first row, your code needs to detect which row of data is currently being fetched and only echo the column value for the desired row.

For example, in pseudo code:

```
//  include inside of fetch loop
if (current_row is row2){
    echo 3rd_column_data_value;
}
```